# $watchGroup get value from array.rows

Tags: arrays, angularjs, watch

In my code, I am watching over multiple arrays and I need to get values from all those arrays when the value changes. I am able to get the arrays with new values but not able to get a single value from the array.

I have tried creating a new array and pushing the entire updated array and then loop in that array.

```
$scope.$watchGroup([
    "Flag.rows", "IncludeUserDomain.rows", "SubdomainPrefix.rows",
    "USERID_New.rows", "PortalURL.rows"
], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
        console.log(newValues[1]);
}, true);
```

The console log output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X262c.jpg

[image]

I am trying to get qText value. However when I try the following, it is undefined:

```
console.log(newValues[1].qText);
```

Comment: Use `console.log(newValues[1][0].qText);`

Comment: The [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) method does not have an optional third argument for deep watch. Only the [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method has a deep watch option.